# Multiple IDs # on one css

Tags: css

I'm trying to have one css for multiple IDs, but it's not working

```
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel-default:last-child {
    border-top:thin solid #b11f26;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /*Gradient on box */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child {
    background: url('../introduction/images/WNF/wineglass.png') no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

Is it possible to have multiple IDs and how do I do it, if I have one ID and then the > .panel.. its working and then the same code for the next ID, but that will give me a big code, thats why I want to make one style to multiple IDs.

I need to use three different ID names but css code would be the same for all three.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change

```
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel-default:last-child
#c178, #c179, #c180 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child
```

to

```
#c178 > .panel , #c179 > .panel , #c180 > .panel
#c178 > .panel-default:last-chil, #c179 > .panel-default:last-chil, #c180 > .panel-default:last-child
#c178 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child, #c179 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child, #c180 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child
```

hope i help

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
#c178 > .panel, 
#c179 > .panel, 
#c180 > .panel {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

You have to specify that the panel is inside each div.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#c178 > .panel, #c179 > .panel, #c180 > .panel {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
#c178 .panel-default:last-child, #c179 .panel-default:last-child, #c180 > .panel-default:last-child {
    border-top:thin solid #b11f26;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    /*Gradient on box */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
#c178> .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child, #c179> .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child, #c180 > .panel-default > .panel-body:last-child {
    background: url('../introduction/images/WNF/wineglass.png') no-repeat 95% 50%;
}
```

also I would condider using the same class for all those divs and apply styling to that class

Answer (score -1):

add a common class to your different IDs, for example

```
<div id="c178" class="example"></div>
<div id="c179" class="example"></div>
<div id="c180" class="example"></div>
```

this way you can use the class `example` to style the different IDs